# Codeigniter get_instance function from external script

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am calling from the shell a php file that is not in the Codeigniter application folder and so I need an instance of the application and I have used

```
<?php 

const BASEPATH = "/"; 
require './system/core/Controller.php';

$CI =& CI_Controller::get_instance();
var_dump($CI->load->helper('url'));
```

but I get error:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'load' of non-object
```

Comment: the superobject gets instantiated if you call a controller - if you don't, you don't have a superobject ;) the only way how this would work is to instantiate a new CI_Controller - take a closer look here https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L467

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question, but as you can see still issue

Comment: i think you dont understand me - you've to instantiate it something like `new Welcome()`

Comment: can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: will do a bit later ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only thing you've to do is to try to create an instance...
The best way to do this is to actually include the index.php - but to suppress the output

the following should work

```
ob_start();
require_once('./index.php');
ob_end_clean();

var_dump($CI->load->helper('url'));
```