# How to use CodeIgniter Libraries in pure Php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a project that mix CodeIgniter and pure Php, and at some point I need to use a function of a CodeIgniter library in a pure php script.

But when I try to include the library, using the *include* Php statement, I get the error :

```
No direct script access allowed
```

Raise by this line at the beginning of the library :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Is there a way to define the 'BASEPATH' variable in pure Php ? Or an other way to access to the library ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: http://www.php.net/constants

Comment: CodeIgniter libraries are limited to use only within CI framework. It's possible to use it if you can trick to include it.

You should never modify CI libraries to make it work with your pure PHP.

Comment: It's not really a native CodeIgniter library, I wrote it by following the CI documentation : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: use ci in your external script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708077/codeigniter-get-instance-function-from-external-script/49711696#49711696

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Remove the conditional statement `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit...` from the script.
2. Define a value for BASEPATH before you include the CodeIgniter library file. i.e. `define(BASEPATH, 'some_value');` It probably won't matter what value you use. But in a CodeIgniter setup BASEPATH is the absolute path to the `system` folder so you will probably want to do the same.

Depending on the library you are trying to use you *might* be successful. You won't be successful if the library you want depends on other parts of the framework.